# Is there a way to get all values from all text fields in a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a page with this layout

> Apple [checkbox] [amount(textField)]
>
> Oranges [checkbox] [amount(textField)]
>
> [Submit Button]

I know how to get the values of the checkboxes using getParameterValues() in my servlet. is there a way to do the same with the values of text fields?. Basically I want to know the quantity of oranges or apples then display it on a different JSP

Answer (score 0):

You can name your text fields that they will start with "someParameter" and then use:

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.Map" %>
Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
for(String parameter : parameters.keySet()) {
    if(parameter.toLowerCase().startsWith("someParameter")) {
        String[] values = parameters.get(parameter);
        //your code here
    }
}
```

or use JSTL:

```
<c:forEach var="par" items="${paramValues}">
    <c:if test="${fn:startsWith(par.key, 'someParameter')}"> 
${par.key} = ${par.value[0]}; //your code here
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```